# Java WebSocket Jetty

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

Есть простенький веб сервер на Jetty, суть работы довольно проста.
Клиент посылает другому пользователю сообщение в виде json строки, сервер
обрабатывает её и записывает сообщение в базу. 
По запросу, пользователь может получить историю сообщений с другим пользователем.
**Вопрос:** 
Всё это нужно переделать на Web Socket. Мне не понятно, по какому принципу тогда обрабатывать запросы.
Если я буду записывать сообщения так же в базу, то как пользователю проверять, пришло ли новое сообщение? 
Есть идея обрабатывать сообщение, записать его в базу, а потом переслать нужному пользователю, но мне кажется это будет не правильно.

Comment: почему вы думаете, что это будет не правильно?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman мне кажется это будет медленно работать, да и я не имею опыта в этом, поэтому решил узнать ответ от более опытных людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете записать в базу и после сохранения разослать сообщение другим пользователям. Если процесс сохранения в базу занимает слишком много времени, то тогда можно проводить его параллельно с рассылкой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду пробовать.